# How to resolve: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_Length' I've tried everything

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, typeerror

> Here's another similar question that didn't worked for me even it's almost the same situation [How to resolve TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_MAX_LENGTH' in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701350/how-to-resolve-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-max-le)

```
from django.db import models
import string
import random


def generate_unique_code():
    lenght = 6

    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=lenght))
        if Room.objects.filter(code=code).count() == 0:
            break

    return code

# Create your models here.

class Room(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_Length=8, default="", unique=True)
    host = models.CharField(max_Length=50, unique=True)
    guest_can_pause = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    votes_to_skip = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Are you positive that the correct syntax is `max_Length` and not something like `max_length` or `maxLength`? The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) says `max_length`.

Comment: I already tried all of that

Comment: The argument is `max_length`, all lowercase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument '\_MAX\_LENGTH' in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701350/how-to-resolve-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-max-le)

Answer (score 3):

Documentation says that the argument is called [`max_length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField.max_length) **not** `max_Length`.

Case matters.